# I noticed after the last lead someone reneged but it actually helped me so I just let it go

Tags: euchre

I had made it spades I played the jack of clubs opponent put on the ace of clubs and I had low clubs but more and higher spades. If the gentleman had played properly he probably would have euchred me. So instead of trying to get 2 points when really played right they would of got the 2. But because he reneged and wasnt played right i might have got a point or i may have gotten euchred. We very seldom count a 2 points for reneg its either corrected. For a lone its counted as 4 points otherwise you could just reneg so person couldnt get their lone hand. He had the right bower when he reneged so i thought anyway i wasnt getting 2. Did I do the right thing to let it go?

Answer (score 1):

Most Euchre rules leave it the opponent (you in this case) to call the renege. They don't explicitly identify it as optional, but neither do the penalty sections go on to say what to do if you don't call it (i.e., there's no penalty for not calling a renege).

For instance, from [these rules](https://euchreplayingcards.com/rules-for-euchre/):

> the opposing team is rewarded two points **if it is caught**

and

> [unintentional reneges] are still **callable** by opponents as reneging

(emphasis added)

Comment: The [Laws of Rubber Bridge](https://cdn.acbl.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Laws-of-Rubber-Bridge.pdf) are more speccific: "**Law 64 - Procedure after Establishment of a Revoke** .... (D). ... When any established revoke, including one not
subject to penalty, causes damage to the non-offending side insufficiently compensated by the Law, the offending side should transfer additional tricks so as to restore equity.*"

Comment: Yeah, the bridge mindset is quite different.